# sucess function not working in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I was  getting alert value after change function but after success function, I not getting any values

my ajax page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#customer").change(function() {
        var customer_type = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var dataString = 'customer_type='+ customer_type;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/capms_v3/ajax/getcust_type.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(customerData) {
                alert(data);
                alert("test");
                if(customerData) {
                    var customer = [customerData];
                    customerData.forEach(function(item) {
                        var data = '<tr>';
                        data+= '<td colspan="4"> </td>';
                        data+= '<td align="right">'+item.company_id+'</td>';
                        data+= '<td align="right">'+item.company_name+'</td>';
                        data+='</tr>';
                        $('.appendData').append(data);
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#heading").hide();
                    $("#records").hide();
                    $("#no_records").show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

my array values are not coming after the success function but in getcusttype page values was coming in an array

getcusttype.php

```
<?php 
     //header("Content-type:application/json");
       include 'db.php';
       $db=DbConnect();

   if($_REQUEST['customer_type']) {
     $sql = "SELECT company_id,company_name FROM ca_customer WHERE customer_type ='".$_REQUEST['customer_type']."'";
     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     $data = array();
     while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
     $data[] = $rows;
              }
              echo json_encode($data);
              } else {
              echo 0;
              }?>

  //var customer =[{"0":"1","company_id":"1","1":"Win Win 
  web","company_name":"Win Win web"},{"0":"7","company_id":"7","1":"New 
  Company","company_name":"New Company"},
  {"0":"10","company_id":"10","1":"Murugan Super 
  Store","company_name":"Murugan Super Store"}];
```

after the success: function(customerdata) if I alert(data) values was getting alert I don't know what error I have made.

view

```
<select id="customer" name="customer_type" class="form-control">
 <option value="">Select Customer Type</option>
  <?php 
     foreach($all_ca_customer_type as $ca_customer_type)
      {
    $selected = ($ca_customer_type['customer_type_id'] == $this->input->post('customer_type')) ? ' selected="selected"' : "";
    echo '<option value="'.$ca_customer_type['customer_type_id'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$ca_customer_type['customer_type_name'].'</option>';
                            } 
                            ?>
                        </select>
 <tbody class="appendData">
    </tbody>
```

not getting values after success function.if anybody face this problem help me.thanks in advance

Comment: Did you know `mysql_` functions are deprecated and removed since php 7.0? You should consider switching over to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). It's actually a well known fact that with every call to a `mysql_` function, Kim Jong Un gains 1 plutonium.

Comment: `alert(data);` there's no `data` variable - try `alert(customerData);`

Comment: If you're not getting any alert, then you're not getting to the `success:` - add an `error:` handler and check the error message

Comment: uncomment `header("Content-type:application/json");` in `getcusttype.php`

Comment: What error message are you getting the in `error:` handler?

Comment: thankyou freedomn-m no error is displaying

Comment: Enable PHP errors and then visit `getcusttype.php` are you getting an output that you expect?

Comment: Does the alert not fire, or does the alert just pop up empty? Like do you not enter your success function, or? Try `alert(html);` in your success function, if you even enter the function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `header("Content-type:application/json");` in `getcusttype.php`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `alert()` function is referencing `data` Where does data come from? Try `alert(customerData)` in place of `alert(data)`.

```
   success: function(customerData) {
        alert(data);
        alert("test");
        if(customerData) {
            var customer = [customerData];
            customerData.forEach(function(item) {
                var data = '<tr>';
                data+= '<td colspan="4"> </td>';
                data+= '<td align="right">'+item.company_id+'</td>';
                data+= '<td align="right">'+item.company_name+'</td>';
                data+='</tr>';
                $('.appendData').append(data);
            });
        } else {
            $("#heading").hide();
            $("#records").hide();
            $("#no_records").show();
        }
    }
```

---

If you're looking to alert the row that your appending you should move the `alert(data)` call, as is, down into your `forEach()` block after you declare your `data` variable.
Ex:

```
customerData.forEach(function(item) {
    var data = '<tr>';
        data+= '<td colspan="4"> </td>';
        data+= '<td align="right">'+item.company_id+'</td>';
        data+= '<td align="right">'+item.company_name+'</td>';
        data+='</tr>';
    alert(data);
    $('.appendData').append(data);
});
```